# creating regular expression in asp.net using letters and numbers

Tags: asp.net, regex

I want to use regular expression using letters and numbers but it has to be minimum of 5 letters and at-least one number

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,}$
```

You can try this as well.A `lookahead` will make sure there is a number present.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uE3cC4/6

EDIT:

If you want atleast on letter too use:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,}$
```

Comment: it takes if i put 44444 but i need minimum 5 characters plus at least one number so it is combination both letters and numbers.  thx

Comment: no, it is accepting 44444 but it does not accept if i do rrrrr so it requires one number

Comment: @moe you said at `least one number`.then how can `rrrrr` be `valid`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,}
```

See [.NET DEMO](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3d.*%5cd)%5ba-zA-Z0-9%5d%7b5%2c%7d&i=qwrqeer4%0d%0aweq34%0d%0a34rr%0d%0a342wrweg%0d%0arwwtfg%0d%0a&o=m)

Comment: it takes if i put 44444 but i need minimum 5 characters plus at least one number so it is combination both letters and numbers.  thanks